# Java:Stream closed Exception

Tags: java

I  have a `RandomAcessfile`  which i should  make  empty  before   write data  inside it. when  i make `ini.setlength(0)`  my  code  catches  error  that says:

```
"stream is  closed" java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:213)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at locckGroovy.main(locckGroovy.groovy:82)
```

here  is my  code,  what  should i change?(is  it  possbile  that  ini.setlength()  this  function closes  the ini  channel  at  all  and  then  i try  to  close  it  secondly in  my  finally  code?):

```
class locckGroovy {
    private static void setValue(String tag, Element element , String input) {
        NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
        node.setTextContent(input);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C://Users//user//Desktop//conf1.xml");
        String content = '';
        BufferedReader s;
        BufferedWriter w;
        RandomAccessFile  ini;
        FileLock lock;
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
        Document  doc=null;
        String start, startDate, endDate, runAs, makeVersion, patch;
        try {
            ini = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rwd");
            lock = ini.getChannel().lock();
            String sCurrentLine;
            s = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));


            while ((sCurrentLine = s.readLine()) != null) {
                content += sCurrentLine;
            }

            s.close();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes('UTF-8'));
            doc = dBuilder.parse(stream);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("localAttributes");
            int m = 0;


            for (int i = 0; i != nList.getLength(); ++i) {
                Node child = nList.item(i);
                if (!(child instanceof Element))
                    continue;

                if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element = (Element) child;


                    setValue("runAs", element, "true");
                }

            }

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            StreamResult result1 = new StreamResult(bos);
            try {
                transformer.transform(source, result1);
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();
            String data = bos.toString();
            if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                ini.setLength(0);
                w = new BufferedWriter(Channels.newWriter(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));
                w.write(data);
                w.close();


            }


        }finally {
            lock.release();
            ini.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception? **Include the stacktrace in your question.**

Comment: ini.setLength(0);

Comment: Is  it  possbile that  thui  syncronized  write  processRandomAccessFile ini = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw"); tooks   too  much  time and  i  can't  close stream  bacaus  of  it  ?

Comment: when   i  comment  ini.length(0)  i  have  exception on w.close()  too

Comment: Takes too much time? Even if it did, that wouldn't affect anything. It's not like the execution would move forward before the writing is finished. Is that the full actual code you're using?

Comment: no  it's  a part  of  it  i will  upload     fulll version  now

Comment: Just include the relevant parts.

Comment: You close the stream and therefore the file at `s.close();`.

Comment: if  i remove s.close()  how can  i close  bufferdreader?

Comment: I have  removed  it in  finally  block  code but  than  i  get  second  error:

Comment: Channels  closedChannel Exception on  locn.relesae()

Comment: Jesus, dude. There's a great tool called google.

Comment: thank   you    i know  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of ini.getChannel() is unique for the RAF, closing it indirectly by yourBufferedReader.close() will also close the channel.

You need actually to reset it position to 0 instead and not close the bufferedreader.

You can close everything up after all usage.

Comment: what  do  you mean  by reset it position to 0

Comment: yourRaF.seek(0)

Comment: Thnak  youi  guess  i  had  extra  channel closes  operation also   i  have removed  it  and  then  it  works  correctly